# If love is an adjective than what do you write for an abstract noun

Tags: nouns, abstract-nouns

If love is an adjective than what do you write for abstract noun is it also gonna be same love and love because if angry is adjective than anger is abstract right. So what is an abstract noun for love?

Comment: Who says "love" can be an adjective?

Comment: @BillJ: Nouns can serve as adjectives, in the form of noun adjuncts; for example "history teacher, hotdog stand, chicken soup"

Comment: No. In "history teacher", "history" is not an adjective but a **noun** functioning as a complement of "teacher". Those items that function as modifiers, as in "brick wall" are nouns not adjectives.

Comment: @Aqsa Have you got an example of a noun phrase in which you think "love" is an adjective?

Comment: Sure,love story,love fest, love nest, love triangle, etc.

Answer (score 2):

"Love" is a noun (and a verb), rather than a "true" adjective.

However, nouns can be used in place of adjectives in the form of "noun adjuncts", which are nouns that are used to describe other nouns.

For example:

> "history teacher": A teacher who teaches the subject of history

> "chicken soup": A soup made from chicken and/or containing che

> "field test": A test that takes place in "the field" (meaning actual use conditions, rather than controlled laboratory conditions)

Comment: Not true. In "history teacher" is not an adjective but a **noun** functioning as a **complement** of "teacher". Not everything that modifies or complements a noun is an adjective.

Comment: That's much better!

Comment: @BillJ: Thank you. Note that "noun adjunct" is distinct from "adjective". (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct).

Comment: "In grammar, a noun adjunct, attributive noun, qualifying noun, or noun (pre)modifier is an optional noun that modifies another noun; it is a noun functioning as a pre-modifier in a noun phrase" Wikipedia.  But I call 'em "adjectival nouns". And I will tell you why: an adjunct is something added to something. Whereas an adjective in English usually precedes a noun. I guess I should write a paper about that....

Answer (score 1):

Although you can use love in an adjective-like way as a [noun adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct) like "I'm a [love machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Love_Machine_(The_Miracles_song))", in its normal everyday role love usually acts as a noun or verb. The words that correspond most in the anger/angry paradigm would be "lovely" (although it's had a meaning shift and is more like "beautiful" rather than "full of love") or just its participle-adjective form "loving", like "that was a loving thing to do", and there "loving" basically means "full of love".

Comment: What is the function of "love" in "love shack", and "love juice"?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey noun adjuncts also

Comment: I think it's better to treat "love-machine" as a single word, a compound noun, rather than a syntactic construction consisting of head + modifier (or complement).

Answer (score 0):

Love is a feeling. A type of abstract nouns are feelings. And adjectives are descriptions to something. **Lovely** or **loved** would be an adjective, and love would be an abstract noun.